# Destroying app from Marathon puts it into the Deployments. How to destroy app in marathon?

Tags: linux, devops, mesos, marathon, mesosphere

I am trying to destroy my sample apps that I deployed using marathon framework. Now I am trying to destroy that app but unfortunately, I can not destroy them for some reason.

I have already tried:

1. restarting marathon service on my slave.
2. restarting mesos-manager.
3. restarting mesos-master.
4. checked if they are all connected to the each other properly.

Why would an app go in the deployment mode when I destroy it?
Is there any way to destroy this app now?
Errors I am getting are as follows,

1. While destroying app
   Error Destroying Application
   Error destroying null: App '/null' does not exist
2. Spawning a new app
   App is locked by one or more deployments. Override with the option '?force=true'. View details at '/v2/deployments/

Answer (score 0):

Just tried

1. Restarting mesos-master
2. Restarting mesos-slave
3. Cleared cache for the mesos-zookeeper
4. Went inside mesos-manager docker image and restarted all services.

One of these is bound to work